# AdBlock thinks my websocket request is an ad

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, google-chrome-extension, websocket, adblock

I Have a simple back-end app on a Google cloud virtual machine. It receives websocket connections and sends some simple messages to clients. I also have nginx server running on same machine, listening to 443 port and redirecting requests to my application (http://127.0.0.1:8080). Everything is secured by a valid SSL certificate, so requests are made through `https://` and `wss://`.

Now I'm writing Angular front-end application that connects to my server like this:

```
return webSocket({
      url: `wss://www.mydomain.site/${path}`,
      closeObserver: {
        next: (event: CloseEvent) => { console.log(event) }
      }
    }).multiplex(() => {}, () => {}, () => true)
```

When I try to run the code in my browser with `AdBlock` chrome extension enabled, it thinks that my request to websocket is an ad and blocks it. So my server doesn't even receive Upgrade request and browser logs `WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.site/something' failed`.
When AdBlock is disabled, everything works fine: Request is sent to my server and incoming messages are received on the browser.

Also, when I try sending request directly to my app and bypassing nginx proxy like this: `ws://www.mydomain.site:8080/something`, everything works fine with AdBlock enabled.

My website doesn't use ads, so I don't care if users have AdBlock on or off, and asking users to disable AdBlock might be annoying for them and bad for UX.

My question is, what can I do to prevent AdBlock from treating my `wss://` request as an ad and blocking it?

My domain is `.site`, can that be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I was previously using no-ip.com to redirect the websocket using certbot TLS system with domain name, but no-ip was requesting an update every month which is really tedious work for a 8$/mo server hosted on google cloud.

I started using duckdns which doesn't require every month update, and when I investigated for 5 hours why it couldn't connect, it was adblock which doesn't like duckdns.com it seems ...

You can use no-ip if you are not afraid to click "update" every month, or find another service which isn't blocked by adblock :)

Comment: Same problem. Easylist blocks my domain where I want to use websockets.